# PHP recreate array if it contains certain values

Tags: php, arrays

I have `$fruits_arr`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 213
            [fruit] => banana
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 438
            [fruit] => apple
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 154
            [fruit] => peach
        )
)
```

And `$ids_arr`:

```
Array ( 
  [0] => 213
  [1] => 154 
)
```

I want to recreate `$fruits_arr` to have only array items where `id` is equal to a value from `$ids_arr`. I also want to maintain the index/array order of `$fruits_arr`.

I'm using the following:

```
$selected_fruits = array();

foreach( $fruits_arr as $fruit ) :
    if ( in_array( $fruit['id'], $ids_arr ) ) :
        $selected_fruits[] = $fruit;
    endif;
endforeach;

print_r( $selected_fruits );
```

It seems to work but I am wondering if there is a shorter, better way to accomplish this in the latest PHP version.

Comment: This looks more like a question for Code Review.

Comment: Interesting i didn;t know about that stack exhange

Comment: BTW When showing us the contents of arrays it is better to use [`var_export()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php)

Comment: Instead of `foreach` maybe you could use [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

Comment: You suggest wanting to keep your existing keys on the fruit array, but you are not adding the associated key to your selected fruits.  Which you could easily.  Or perhaps I misread that:  'I want to maintain index/array order'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use array_filter to make it more concise, but it will not be much and could make your code less readable. If possible chose readability over length of code.

```
$selected_fruits = array_filter($fruits_arr, function ($el) use ($ids_arr) {
    return in_array($el['id'], $ids_arr, true);
});
```

or you can wait for PHP 7.4 (due to come out at the end of the year) and use arrow functions.

```
$selected_fruits = array_filter($fruits_arr, fn ($el) => in_array($el['id'], $ids_arr, true));
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/4UC41

Answer (score 2):

This is not a shorter or newer way, but perhaps instead of performing in_array for every iteration, you could use array_flip and then use [isset](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) to check for the key:

```
$ids_arr = array_flip($ids_arr);
$selected_fruits = [];

foreach ($fruits_arr as $k =>  $fruit) {
    if (isset($ids_arr[$fruit["id"]])) {
        $selected_fruits[$k] = $fruit;
    }
}
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/8dNZp)

Answer (score 0):

If the array is associative (use array_column for that) then you can use array_intersect_key to do the job.

```
$fruits_arr = array_column($fruits_arr, Null, "id");

$result = array_intersect_key($fruits_arr, array_flip($ids_arr));

var_dump($result);
```

https://3v4l.org/jQo6E

Answer (score 0):

Keeping it simple, a loop where you remove items that are not in your keep array.

```
<?php

$fruits =
[
    'foo' => [
        'id' => 1,
        'fruit' => 'banana'
    ],
    'bar' => [
        'id' => 2,
        'fruit' => 'orange'
    ],
    'baz' => [
        'id' => 3,
        'fruit' => 'pear'
    ],    
];

$keep_ids = [1,3];

foreach($fruits as $k=>$v)
    if(!in_array($v['id'], $keep_ids))
        unset($fruits[$k]);

var_export($fruits);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'foo' => 
  array (
    'id' => 1,
    'fruit' => 'banana',
  ),
  'baz' => 
  array (
    'id' => 3,
    'fruit' => 'pear',
  ),
)
```